# SampleSyncAdapter storing password plain text?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I am trying to get my head around Android AccountManager and OAuth.
What i would like to do is not let the phone have access to the password. (That is what Google suggests: "[Be Smart About Security!](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html)")
So i checkout the Google sample application [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) and start reading through the code. then i see this happen in AuthenticatorActivity:

```
private AccountManager mAccountManager;
private String mPassword;

 /**
 * ... Sets the
 * AccountAuthenticatorResult which is sent back to the caller. We store the
 * authToken that's returned from the server as the 'password' for this
 * account - so we're never storing the user's actual password locally.
 *
 * @param result the confirmCredentials result.
 */
public void handleLogin(View view) {
    ....
    mPassword = mPasswordEdit.getText().toString();    
    ....
    Log.d(TAG, "mPassword set to Account:" + mAccountManager.getPassword(account));
}

private void finishLogin(String authToken) {
    ....
    mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, mPassword, null);        
    ....
}
```

This Log message is "mPassword set to Account:test".
This is in some way understandable when you read the rest because of this

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ....
    return NetworkUtilities.authenticate(mUsername, mPassword);     
    ....
}
```

if the password was a token this would not work.

Also i would expect the rest of the code to work differently in Authenticator on getAuthToken()
I Assume i am completely wrong about something but i just want to use AccountManager to store the result of an OAuth "Dance" so that i can use this Account to authenticate my JSON RESTful service.

Can any one shine a light on this?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation we can read this:

> It's important to understand that AccountManager is not an encryption service or a keychain. It stores account credentials just as you pass them, **in plain text**. On most devices, this isn't a particular concern, because it stores them in a database that is only accessible to root. But on a rooted device, the credentials would be readable by anyone with adb access to the device.

Thus, as I understand, here is a problem of misuse of the words (password and token). I guess the procedure is the following:

1. You ask a user to provide a login and password.
2. In your application you somehow send this login and password to your server.
3. Basing on this information your server generates a token and sends back to your application.
4. AccountManager stores this token in plain text and then this token is used to authenticate your user.

Comment: What if the token invalidates after a certain amount of time?  I guess you just have to re-prompt the user for their password in that case.  But many services (e.g. Facebook) are never prompting me for a password, so either 1) the token they generate never expires, making it basically as good as a password in terms of security, or 2) they are storing my password (plain text or encrypted).